# Rest: Passing an array of xml payload request

Tags: xml, rest, jaxb, jersey, jackson

Got a controller method like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/{id}")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response postEntities(final Domain[] domains, @PathParam("id") final Long id)
```

If I pass a JSON array of domains it works fine and marshaling works fine. But for xml requests I tried to wrap `<Domain></Domain>` around `<Domains></Domains>`, controller throws `204 - No Content` back.
Example:

```
<Domains>
 <Domain>
  .
  .
  .
 </Domain>
 <Domain>
  .
  .
  .
 </Domain>
</Domains>
```

Comment: `204 No Content` is no error. What response do you expect?

Comment: I am sending some request payload which is not being recognized by rest controller.

Comment: How do you know that? `204 No Content` does not indicate an error. Why do you think the request payload is not recognized?